# Extracting all the lines before IF block in Java AST parser

Tags: java, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

I am using java AST parser (eclipse API) to  parse java files. I want to extract all the lines before any "IF" condition in methods. Can anyone please tell how to do it. Following is the example code:

```
    Void method1()
      {
       L1:  System.out.println("This is first line");
       L2:  System.out.println("Line 2"); 
       L3:
       L4  if(1==0)
       L5:   {
       L6:     System.out.println("no cond"); 
       L7:  }
       L8:
       }


      output:System.out.println("This is first line");
      System.out.println("Line 2");
```

Comment: In the example I provided there are three line before "IF", L1, L2 L3. I want to extract these three line.

Comment: Any idea about it, is it possible to do using eclispe API? Thanks!

Comment: These comments should be a part of the question, instead of adding comments, edit your question.